# Thrust's exclusive_scan_by_key function takes the same amount of time as a sequential implementation?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, thrust

I'm relatively new to Thrust and I'm trying to perform a segmented scan. Here is my code, which you should be able to run as-is:

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <chrono>

// Sequential scan for CPU
float* test_seqScan(float* in, int s, int m) {
    float* out = new float[s * m];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        out[i * m] = 0;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 1; j < m; j++) {
            out[i * m + j] = out[i * m + j - 1] + in[i * m + j - 1];
        }
    }

    return out;
}

void test_sumScan(thrust::device_vector<float> dev_in, thrust::device_vector<int> dev_keys, int s, int m) {
    // Allocate device memory for output
    thrust::device_vector<float> dev_out(s * m);

    thrust::exclusive_scan_by_key(thrust::device, dev_keys.begin(), dev_keys.end(), dev_in.begin(), dev_out.begin());
}

int main(){
    int s = 100;
    int m = 100000;

    float* seq_in = new float[s * m];

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            seq_in[i * m + j] = j + 1;
        }
    }

    thrust::host_vector<float> par_in(s * m);
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            par_in[i * m + j] = j + 1;
        }
    }

    thrust::host_vector<int> keys(s * m);
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            keys[i * m + j] = i;
        }
    }

    thrust::device_vector<float> dev_in = par_in;
    thrust::device_vector<int> dev_keys = keys;

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    test_seqScan(seq_in, s, m);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();

    std::cout << "Sequential duration: " << duration1 << "\n\n";

    auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    test_sumScan(dev_in, dev_keys, s, m);
    auto t4 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();

    std::cout << "Parallel duration: " << duration2 << "\n\n";
}
```

My issue is that both these snippets of code take *exactly* the same amount of time to run regardless of how small or large I set `s` and `m`. I assume that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what; can anyone point out the issue?

Comment: One thing that could be giving you worse timings is that modern GPUs nowadays sometimes need to be working for some time to "warm up" before you can take a meaningful measurement. Try calling `test_sumScan` a few times in a loop before taking the time measurement.

Comment: Also just as a remark: `chrono::high_resolution_clock` sounds nice, but the C++ standard doesn't say that it has to be a steady clock which is even more important than the resolution for benchmarking (non-steady clock could even give negative timings independent of how high the resolution is). Therefore I would use `chrono::steady_clock`. Depending on the compiler this will not make any difference, but I have at least not heard of any implementation where `high_resolution_clock` is actually better than `steady_clock`.